# selenium open net tab in a existing windows

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have open a browser windows with something page  and when I run the code :

```
 public class First {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    String exePath = "C:\\Users\\Arsed\\Desktop\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", exePath);

    WebDriver driver=new EdgeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

it open a new windows with "facebook"  not a new tab in the existing windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Selenium's default behaviour.
At least it opened a window.
You will not intercept an already-opened browser's window (for example the one you read my answer in now) with Selenium WebDriver.

You could do it perhaps with Robot class in Java or with AutoIt.